# Как сделать правильную пагинацию laravel?

Tags: laravel

У меня есть шаблон в котором выводится вьюшка Ajax-ом 
Ajax отправляет POST запрос с id компании вот сюда:

```
Route::post('/market/getCompany', ['as' => 'getCompany', 'uses' =>'MarketController@getCompany']);
```

Вот код MarketController:

```
public function getCompany(Request $request)
    {
        $company = Company::where('id', $request->id)->first();
        if(isset($company)){
            $articles = $this->getArticles();
            return view('layouts.market', compact('company','articles'));
        }
        return 'no results';
    }
     public function getArticles()
    {
        $articles = Articles::orderBy('price','desc')->simplePaginate(30);
        $articles->withPath('/market/articles');
        return $articles;
    }
```

Собственно проблема в том, что если я перехожу на следующую страницу пагинации, то у меня вылетает результат метода `getCompany(); return 'no results';` т.к страница сбрасывает Ajax и обращается по адресу который предназначен для загрузки вьюхи, но если в web.php я прописываю это:

```
Route::get('/market/articles', ['as' => 'getArticles', 'uses' =>'MarketController@getArticles']);
```

то в таком случае у меня просто вылетает JSON ответ в браузере.
Посоветуйте как сделать это все качественно. 
Менял ajax на get запросы, поведение не меняется.

Comment: А модель `Company` - это своего рода категории `Articles`?

Comment: @РустамГимранов, Company и Articles вообще не зависят друг от друга, в Articles лежат вообще всевозможные товары, т.е после ввода id компании на страницу загружается информация о ней(компании) и я добавляю товары в неё из общего списка.

Comment: Если они никак не зависят, то по какой причине вы делаете проверку `if(isset($company))` перед тем как товары вывести?

Comment: @РустамГимранов , чтоб в случае отсутствия id вернуть 'no results'

Comment: Тогда лучше `->firstOrFail()`, чтобы вернуть 404. И вместо `Route::post` должен быть `get`, однозначно. А для погрузки `articles` использовать json ответ для генерации html на клиенте `if (request()->ajax())  {return response()->json(...)`, либо создать отдельную view и возвращать готовый html.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getCompany(Request $request)
{
    $company = Company::findOrFail($request->id);
    if(!is_null($company)){
        $articles = $this->getArticles($request);
        return view('layouts.market', compact('company','articles'));
    }
    return 'no results';
}
 public function getArticles(Request $request)
{
    $articles = Articles::orderBy('price','desc')->simplePaginate(30);
    $articles->withPath('/market/articles');
    return $articles;
}
```

Попробуйте так
А вообще сделайте получение статей компании через relations, если статьи относятся к какой либо компании.